# How to know which way is up and how to rotate object to a specific place

Tags: edit-mode

Two questions but I'm sure they are both easily answered especially the first.

Firstly I imported an .obj file (3d image of a timber park bench) rescaled it and output to 'special' giTF for Flight simulator. In Flight simulator the object was upside down which I easily fixed but how can you tell if an imported object is upside down?

Secondly also to do with rotation is how to rotate an object so that it appears as it would in real life. Here I refer to a canoe which has is has a 'bent' top (the ends are higher than the centre). In real life when upside down it would not be rotated 180 degrees it would fall back slightly due to the difference between  the ends and the middle - hope I have explained myself.
Is there an easy method to find the correct rotation other than try and check result? Here is an  image of the canoe which I would like to rotate so that it looks correct when upside down as well as an image of a real canoe upside down.[image]

[image]

Comment: for the 2nd question: you could make a rigid body out of it with shape mesh, then it will fall "as in real life". If it has fallen you can then keyframe the location and delete the rigid body.

Comment: Thanks for your reply but I have no idea what you mean. Maybe I should have described the canoe as having 3 points of contact with the ground when inverted, each end and also the top rail half way along (which would then be at the bottom). The top rail of a canoe is lower in the middle than the ends and therefore when you turn a canoe upside down and place it on the ground it would naturally fall over slightly to one side. I just wondered if there was an easy way other than trail and error to rotate the object to the correct degree.

Comment: For the first - try to Apply Rotation Ctrl+A ... For the second (Chris is right) just search for Rigid Body physics tutorial (if nobody provides step by step A here) ... be ware of pivot point position for center of gravity. I don't think there is another option.

Comment: Thanks for your input.  Lately I have been improvising in a similar way.   To ensure multi faced (.glTF) scenery objects such as an aircraft are the correct say wingspan I temporarily add a mesh cube with the respective axis set to the real aircraft's wingspan and then move it on top  of (in this example) the wing and then if it isn't correct I Scale the object until it is and then remove the temporary mesh cube.  I find this HEAPS easier than using the 'Measure tool'.  And for the canoe  I add a mesh cube or plane, place the canoe above and rotate until the three contact points touch.